# In Eigen C++ : mix complex matrix and real matrix

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to add a real matrix to a complex matrix and store the result in another complex matrix. It seems that Eigen does not support such operation. The following code failed at compilation stage. The reason I want to use such feature is that, in a template function, one input matrix can be real or complex, and I want a uniform code to deal with it. Why doesn't Eigen support such operation ?

```
int main(){
    MatrixXd A(2,2);
    MatrixXcd B(2,2);
    A << -1, -2, -3, -4;
    B.real() << 1, 2, 3, 4;
    B.imag() << 5, 6, 7, 8;

    MatrixXcd C(2, 2);
    C = B + A;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the error messages. They would help you realize that there is no default cast between data types. In order to explicitly cast the `double` matrix to a `std::complex<double>` matrix you would write:

```
C = B + A.cast<std::complex<double>>();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I did not know such a feature before. Now I find it in https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/AsciiQuickReference.txt

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this has been the topic of active development. see http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=279 and https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/pull-requests/194/relax-mixing-type-constraints-for-binary/diff

Now your code compiles and runs just fine (tried with Eigen 3.3.5). The content of  `C` with `cout`:

```
(0,5) (0,6)
(0,7) (0,8)
```